# Use a stored procedure in a Cognos view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cognos

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from a Cognos view. I can run a stored procedure from a view and see the results, however it will not let me save it. When I go to save, it says I have a syntax error at 'EXEC'. Is what I want to do even possible??

SQL block below:

```
EXEC    [dbo].[SEL_EQUIP_FUEL_BY_DATES]
        @EQUIP_IN = N'1',
        @START_DATE = N'12-01-2012',
        @END_DATE = N'12-31-2099',
        @FLAG = 0,
        @init = N'GLR',
        @pid = 156
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hate to tell you, but where in here is a VIEW Involved?

Comment: Cognos cant retrieve data from a stored procedure (or so my Cognos guy tells me) but can read tables and views. So I need a view of my stored procedure. The parameters never change. Hopefully I am making some sense....

Comment: Man, when you talk about SQL Server or SQL in general the word "view" has a meaning. And you do not mention COgnos anywhere in the description. Guess what - we are not telepaths.

Comment: When I execute the code above in the view designer in Sql Server management studio it returns my 16,000+ records I need.

Comment: You'll need to extract the `SELECT` from inside the stored procedure and use that as your "view body" - you cannot execute a stored procedure in the context of a view.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur That is interesting because I am quite sure management studio has no view designer, you know.

Comment: Cognos can quite happily execute a stored procedure, as long as it returns a single result set. If your Cognos guy is telling you otherwise, then you may need a new Cognos guy.

Comment: @TomTom wow, there is a view designer... but alas, i cannot exec a sp within it.  In Mgmt Studio 2012: Right-click Views folder, select New View

Comment: Can you define what you mean by Cognos View?  Do you mean from within a Report using 'Cognos Viewer'?  Or do you mean a Datasource Query Subject in Framework Manager?

Comment: @Andrew is correct, you should be able to import a stored procedure into Framework Manager, set what parameter values you need/want, and run it just fine provided it returns a result set.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be done.

Views can be based on tables, other views and functions, and the body of each view must be a `SELECT` statement.

Stored Procedures aren't easily composed into queries.

Maybe you could change your stored procedure to be a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) instead?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer despite the few unhelpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't paramatise a view, but you can use an inline function.  If Cognos can handle these it would be the way to go.  I suspect they may be able to, as you would select from them just as you would a table or view, only with your parameters as well (Unlike a stored procedure that you have to execute). You would call it with something like

```
Select * from myTableFunction(param1, param2, param3);
```

see [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175924(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175924%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: In Cognos, you can create the Datasource Query Subject via a custom sql query, and insert Cognos Report level 'Prompt' parameters into the query.